# I want to make ref value of my vue project a localstorage array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a variable called notes and I want the value of notes by default be an empty array [] but if there is a data on my localstorage I want the notes value be the localstorage data.

Here's my code

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const newNote = ref("");
const notes = ref([] || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));

const addNote = () => {
  notes.value.push({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
    text: newNote.value,
    date: new Date(),
    bgColor: getRandomColor(),
  });

  newNote.value = "";
  addNotesToLocalStorage(notes);
};

const addNotesToLocalStorage = (notes) => {
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes._rawValue));
};

function getRandomColor() {
  return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ", 100% ,75%,  100%)";
}
</script>
```

When I console the notes array it's giving me an empty array even though the localstorage has data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
const notes = ref([] || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
```

Do it with [*nullish coalescing operator (??)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
const notes = ref(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")??'[]'));
```

And pass `notes.value` when you call `addNotesToLocalStorage(notes.value)` and when you set notes in localStorage just do:

```
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
```

Comment: it works! but why? in a similar vanila js i use the || opreater and it works fine. why is that?

Comment: glad it worked, , the difference between the two operators boils down to the difference between falsy and null/undefined